# OSX 10.9 RDP to Windows 8.1 on AD

Tags: remote-desktop, windows

I am trying to use the default built in apple RDP client to RDP into my Windows 8.1 box but I keep getting the following problem:

```
Remote Desktop Connection for Mac OSX - cannot verify the identity of the computer
```

I've tried a combination of several ways but nothing.

Everything is fine windows to windows.

---not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

I was not aware that Apple shipped a native RDP app, but regardless. I use the one from Microsoft and it works great:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417?mt=12

There is an older one available for direct download from Microsoft but I've used both and prefer the new one. Never had a problem with it and it's FREE.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using "Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac 2.1.1" and do not want to upgrade to "Microsoft Remote Desktop", then the following applies. This was tested using OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite).

The problem is on the Windows 8.1 machine. Make the following changes on the ***Windows machine***.

Enable RDP security layer in Group Policy on the machine:

1. Verify that the firewall allows remote desktop connections with RDP
   (Port 3389).  For private networks, this can be verified by making
   sure the "Allow remote connections to this computer" button is
   selected in the System Properties window. To reach the System
   Properties window, first click the System icon on the Control
   Panel, then click on "Advanced system settings".

[image]

2. Right click on the Windows icon in the lower left corner of the
   Desktop. Select Run from the pop up menu.
3. Type gpedit.msc and click "OK" Result: The Group Policy Editor will
   open.
4. In the left hand side bar, expand Computer
   Configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Remote
   Desktop Services>Remote Desktop Session Host. (Note: In the image
   below, the Standard tab was selected.)

[image]

5. Select "Security".

[image]

6. Change "Require use of specific security layer
   for remote desktop (RDP) connection" to Enabled" and select "RDP" in
   the Options pane.

[image]

7. Change "Require user authentication for remote connections by using
   Network Level Authentication" to "Disabled."

[image]

8. Close Group Policy Editor and reboot the machine for changes to take
   effect.

Source: [Establishing an RDP connection with a Windows 8.1 client from Mac OS X](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/Establishing+an+RDP+connection+with+a+Windows+8.1+client+from+Mac+OS+X)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me. The latest version of Microsoft Remote Desktop shows to enter the user name as "DOMAIN\user name". Well this won't work with Windows 10. I entered my username as "username@domain.com" and voila! It worked. Hope this helps someone as frustrated as myself.